# How to create an index entry for “|| operator”?

Tags: indexing

Following the `\index` quoting rules (prepend a reserved character with a double-quote), I do

```
\index{"|"| operator}
```

but the entry never shows up in the index. Doing these (similar) things does work as expected:

```
\index{"!"! operator}
\index{"| operator}
```

So what is special about '||'? Needless to say, it also doesn't work without double-quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example

```
\index{"|"| operator}
```

should work. However there seem to exist some problems with `hyperref`. Simply put the index key or just the problematic part in braces works:

```
\index{{"|"|} operator}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try using \| instead of || for the operator; both to deal with problematic escaping, but more importantly to get spacing right when you use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you index the symbol in math mode, it should work.  That is, try

```
\index{$"|"|$ operator}
```